# insert an element into a sorted linked list

Tags: ocaml

we had to implement the insert function that can insert a cell into a sorted linked list. My implementation idea was to have two rlists, called previous and current, that will be used to iterate through the list.  At the beginning of the function call, the previous rlist will contain a random integer, and its next field is pointing to the current cell which is the head of the linked_list. I think this is problematic. I finished implementing my idea. I think the method will add the correct integer at the right place in the linked list. However, if the inserted element is at the beginning of the list, then the list is still the old list when using displaying on to the screen, but the old list does indeed have a cell pointing to it, and that cell has the inserted integer.  So I'm not sure how to deal with that.
 I tested my method, and it doesn't work as I described. 
Here is what I did: I inserted -9 to the end of c3. c3 does indeed get -9 at the end of the list.  And then I added 4 inside c5. But then c5 now becomes [5;4;-9]. So it is wrong, it should have [5;4;3;2;1;-9] instead.  So I don't know what is wrong.

I looked up online on how to implement the method so that they can give me some inspirations or hint, but the solutions they provided are usually in Java or other programming languages.

```
type cell = { data : int; next : rlist}
and rlist = cell option ref 

let c1 = {data = 1; next = ref None}
let c2 = {data = 2; next = ref (Some c1)}
let c3 = {data = 3; next = ref (Some c2)}
let c5 = {data = 5; next = ref (Some c3)} 

let rec displayList (c : rlist) =
  match !c with
  | None -> []
  | Some { data = d; next = l } -> d :: (displayList l) 

let cell2rlist (c : cell) :rlist = ref (Some c) 

let bigger((x:int), (y:int)) = (x > y) 



let insert (comp : (int * int) -> bool) (item : int) (listt :rlist)=
  let itemm = {data=item ; next = ref None} in
  let rec helper (prev : rlist) (item : cell) (current: rlist) funcc =
    match !current with
    |None -> (match !prev with 
        |Some w -> w.next := (Some itemm))
    |Some q -> if comp (item.data, q.data) then (itemm.next := (Some q) ; match !prev with 
      |Some w -> w.next := (Some itemm))
        else  prev := !current; current:= !(q.next); (helper prev item current funcc)
  in let previous = ref (Some {data=0; next = listt}) in
  helper previous itemm listt comp
```

Here are examples of the right return values for the code in action:

```
 let l5 = cell2rlist c5;;
val l5 : rlist = ....
(* Messy display deleted. *)



 displayList l5;;
- : int list = [5; 3; 2; 1]


 displayList l5;;
- : int list = [5; 3; 2; 1]


 insert bigger 4 l5;;
- : unit = ()


 displayList l5;;
- : int list = [5; 4; 3; 2; 1]


 insert bigger 9 l5;;
- : unit = ()


 displayList l5;;
- : int list = [9; 5; 4; 3; 2; 1]


 insert bigger 0 l5;;
- : unit = ()


 displayList l5;;
- : int list = [9; 5; 4; 3; 2; 1; 0]
```

But when I ran my codes, here is what I get:

```
insert bigger 10 (ref(Some c5)) ;;
- : unit = ()

c5 ;;
- : cell =
{data = 5;
 next =
  {contents =
    Some
     {data = 3;
      next =
       {contents =
         Some
          {data = 2;
           next = {contents = Some {data = 1; next = {contents = None}}}}}}}}
```

As you can see, if I insert a number that is supposed to be inserted at the beginning of the list, I can't see it.

Here is another example,

```
insert bigger 4 (ref(Some c5)) ;;
- : unit = ()

c5 ;;
- : cell =
{data = 5;
 next =
  {contents =
    Some
     {data = 4;
      next = {contents = Some {data = 1; next = {contents = None}}}}}}
```

So as you see the code doesn't work at all as the updated list should have values `[5;4;3;2;1]` but it has `[5;4;1]` instead.

Here is another example:

```
insert bigger (-9) (ref(Some c3)) ;;
- : unit = ()

c3 ;;
- : cell =
{data = 3;
 next =
  {contents =
    Some
     {data = 2;
      next =
       {contents =
         Some
          {data = 1;
           next = {contents = Some {data = -9; next = {contents = None}}}}}}}}
```

So it seems that the method does insert the element correctly into the list, but the lists that the inserted cell suppose to point to seem to be wrong.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you would give an example where your code is failing rather than examples of how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, here is a session showing a failure of your code:

```
# let (l: rlist) = ref None;;
val l : rlist = {contents = None}
# insert bigger 1 l;;
- : unit = ()
# l;;
- : rlist = {contents = Some {data = 1; next = {contents = None}}}
# insert bigger 0 l;;
- : unit = ()
# l;;
- : rlist = {contents = None}
```

For what it's worth, it would also be good if your code was indented properly.

At any rate, what I see when I look at your code for a short time is this fragment:

```
current:= !(q.next);
helper prev item current funcc
```

It looks to me like you're imagining that the first line here will advance some local variable to point to the next element of the list. But what it actually is doing is modifying the list.

You might want something more like this:

```
helper prev item q.next funcc
```

There are other problems in your code as well. It seems odd, for example, that the `then` part is parenthesized but the `else` part isn't parenthesized.